# how to get table of content from the pdf for iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented ipad application in which i want parse table of content but i dont know how to parse and i dont know which tag is using for table of content.Please give me some advise for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no standard "Table of Contents" tag that I'm aware of in a PDF document.  What documents do you specifically have in mind?

Comment: In Some pdf there is some list indexing of topic and page number.I want to get that type of list.Is it possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can parse a PDF document by using Quartz. Please refer to [PDF Document Parsing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html) for additional information.

Comment: I have read this documents and implemented that funvtions.But there is no any specify how to get table of contents.